# Realtime Database duplicating data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble fetching data from realtime database. Everytime I insert a new data it duplicates the whole table. please help.

here is my output:

[image]

here is my code:

```js
function fetchData() {
  var tbody;
  const dbRef = query(
    ref(database, "vote/"),
    orderByChild("department"),
    equalTo(getUrlParameter("department"))
  );

  onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      tbody += `<tr>
        <td>${childData.judgeName}</td>
        <td>${childData.score1}</td>
        <td>${childData.score2}</td>
        <td>${childData.score3}</td>
        <td>${childData.score4}</td>
        <td>${childData.score5}</td>
      </tr>`;
    });

    $(".list").html(tbody);
  });
}

fetchData();
```

I tried pushing it inside of array but nothing change its still duplicating the whole data/table

Comment: Define `let tbody = ""` within your `onValue` callback. Otherwise, you're always adding to the same ever growing HTML string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```js
function fetchData() {
  const dbRef = query(
    ref(database, "vote/"),
    orderByChild("department"),
    equalTo(getUrlParameter("department"))
  );

  onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    let tbody = ''
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      tbody += `<tr>
        <td>${childData.judgeName}</td>
        <td>${childData.score1}</td>
        <td>${childData.score2}</td>
        <td>${childData.score3}</td>
        <td>${childData.score4}</td>
        <td>${childData.score5}</td>
      </tr>`;
    });

    $(".list").html(tbody);
  });
}
```